# android sqlite query with multiple where

Tags: android, sqlite

Here's my current sqlite code:

```
Cursor c = sqlDatabase.rawQuery("select docid as _id, recipeID from " + TABLE_RECIPE_NAME + 
                " where " + KEY_ownerID + " = ? ", new String[] { ownerID});
```

It works fine, but when I tried adding multiple where to something like this:

```
Cursor c = sqlDatabase.rawQuery("select docid as _id, recipeID from " + TABLE_RECIPE_NAME + 
                " where " + KEY_ownerID + " = ?, " + KEY_partnerID + " = ?, " + KEY_advertiserID + " = ?, " + KEY_chefID + " = ?", new String[] { ownerID, partnerID, advertiserID, chefID });
```

It returns an error. So how do I deal with multiple ?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

change query to:

```
Cursor c = sqlDatabase.rawQuery("select docid as _id, recipeID from " +
TABLE_RECIPE_NAME + " where " + KEY_ownerID + " = ? AND " + KEY_partnerID +
" = ? AND  " + KEY_advertiserID + " = ? AND " + KEY_chefID + " = ?",
new String[] { ownerID, partnerID, advertiserID, chefID });
```

Comment: and what if we are looking same field with three similarity?

Answer (score 6):

You are doing correct but just need to use **AND** or **OR** keyword between each where condition as per your requirement. So try using this once.

Answer (score 3):

Use `AND` and `OR` for multiple `WHERE` clauses. Use parentheses if logical grouping or order is needed.

```
SELECT *
FROM employees
WHERE (last_name = 'Smith' AND first_name = 'Jane') OR (employee_id = 1);
```

[(source)](https://www.techonthenet.com/sqlite/and_or.php)

**Note**

- *This supplemental answer omits the Android code formatting because it makes the SQL hard to read and understand. The reader can do their own formatting.*

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have to use `AND`. You want a query that should return the value in Cursor populated with comparing multiple values. So, you just need to use `AND`. Instead of using a `comma(,)`.  Above answer seems correct but it just lacks the explanation.