# multiple where clause in android

Tags: android, sqlite

```
String slctsummary = "select   Reminder_Id,Reminder_Type,Reminder_Date,Reminder_Time,Reminder_Alert from Reminder_Main where Car_ID="
                +summaryid
                +"AND"
                +Reminder_Date 
                +"="
                +currentdate1;

        Cursor c = sdb.rawQuery(slctsummary,null);
```

i want all the records which satisfy both conditn but it through error.
plz help me to com out of ths
thnx...

the log cat error........

```
> 12-17 11:48:05.250: E/AndroidRuntime(1245):
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>ComponentInfo{com.curious.solutions.finalautoistdiary/com.curious.solutions.finalautoistdiary.ReminderSummary}:
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unrecognized token:
> "1ANDReminder_Date17": , while compiling: select
> Reminder_Id,Reminder_Type,Reminder_Date,Reminder_Time,Reminder_Alert
> from Reminder_Main where Car_ID=1ANDReminder_Date17-NOV-2012
```

Comment: same error is repetd,reminder_id should match the summaryid and reminder_date should match currentdate1

Comment: put space between  1 and "And" and Reminder

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Put some spaces around AND and add these "'" around after =:

```
String Reminder_Main="Reminder_Main",Car_ID="Car_ID",Reminder_Date="Reminder_Date"; 
 Cursor c = sdb.rawQuery("select Reminder_Id ,Reminder_Type,Reminder_Date,Reminder_Time,Reminder_Alert from " + Reminder_Main 
    +" where " + Car_ID + " = ? AND " + Reminder_Date + " = ? " , new String[] { summaryid,currentdate1}); 
c.moveToFirst(); 
c.moveToFirst(); 
int summarycount = c.getCount();
```

If this is not enough to fix the problems, please refer to here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9061437/1503155 to clear up the remaining problem.

Comment: Yes it should be Car_ID +  "='" + summaryid + " AND ?". Sorry for the mistypo. I havent cleared all the problems thats why I gave the link.

Comment: hey thnx for the link it wrkng wll

Comment: String Reminder_Main="Reminder_Main",Car_ID="Car_ID",Reminder_Date="Reminder_Date";
  
  Cursor c = sdb.rawQuery("select Reminder_Id ,Reminder_Type,Reminder_Date,Reminder_Time,Reminder_Alert  from " 
    + Reminder_Main 
    +" where " 
    + Car_ID 
    + " = ? AND  "
    + Reminder_Date + " = ? " , new String[] { summaryid,currentdate1});
  c.moveToFirst();

  
  c.moveToFirst();

  int summarycount = c.getCount();

this code wrks perfctly in my app, the way in which i want it

Answer (score 0):

Here is my try u just focus on whereClause

```
    public List<ModelGps> gellTripByName(String tripName) {
        List<ModelGps> gpses = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase database = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        final String columNames[] = {DBHelper.COLUMN_ID, DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME, DBHelper.COLUMN_LATITUTE, DBHelper.COLUMN_LONGITUDE, DBHelper.COLUMN_ALTITUDE, DBHelper.COLUMN_DATE, DBHelper.COLUMN_TYPE, DBHelper.COLUMN_TRAVEL, DBHelper.COLUMN_SPEED};
        String whereClause = DBHelper.COLUMN_TYPE + " = ? AND " + DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME + " = ? ";
        String[] whereArgs = {"Trip", tripName};

        Cursor cursor = database.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME_GPS, columNames, whereClause, whereArgs, null, null, DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME + " ASC");
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            ModelGps gps = new ModelGps();
            gps.setId(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_ID)));
            gps.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_NAME)));
            gps.setLatitude(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_LATITUTE)));
            gps.setLongitude(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_LONGITUDE)));
            gps.setAltitude(cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_ALTITUDE)));
            gps.setDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_DATE)));
            gps.setType(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_TYPE)));
            gps.setTravel(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_TRAVEL)));
            gps.setSpeed(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBHelper.COLUMN_SPEED)));
            gpses.add(gps);
        }
        database.close();
        cursor.close();
        return gpses;
    }
```