# How to pass two or more selection argument in query method android studio sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am new to Android Studio and android development, I'm having problems passing in multiple parameters into sqlite using a cursor 
I have the following:

```
Cursor cursor = DB.rawQuery("select _id, BookingType as bookingType from " + table + " where " + SqLiteTableData.TableStructure.KEY_BOOKING_DATE+" = ?  AND  " + SqLiteTableData.TableStructure.KEY_BOOKING_TIME+ " = ? " , new String[]{a, b });
```

which in the debugger displays the following:

```
SQLiteDirectCursorDriver: select _id, BookingType as bookingType from Bookings where BookingDate = ?  AND  BookingTime = ?
```

The parameters are not been passed

I have spent ages on this and looked at other posts such as 
[How to pass two or more selection argument in "query" method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757263/how-to-pass-two-or-more-selection-argument-in-query-method)

[android sqlite query with multiple where](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9061410/android-sqlite-query-with-multiple-where)

But cannot get it to work

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct. The parameters are passed correctly.

The debugger does not show parameter values because they are never merged into the SQL command *text*. The database handles the parameters at a later stage.

Comment: Hi @CL thanks, no idea why no records been returned :(

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could use the `query` function instead of rawQuery since it was much easy to handle.

In your case, your query function would be:

```
    Cursor cursor = DB.query(table, "_id, BookingType as bookingType", SqLiteTableData.TableStructure.KEY_BOOKING_DATE+"= ? AND"SqLiteTableData.TableStructure.KEY_BOOKING_TIME+"= ?", new String[]{a,b},null, null);
```